# Renaming file using javascript in Adobe Pro

Tags: javascript

I would like to rename files, currently my files are named with only an **employee ID** but I want to rename the file to **Resume_(ID)**.

> **Example:** from `12345` to `Resume_12345`.

```
this.extractPages(0,0, "Resume_" +(this.documentFileName))
```

The above code works but it only saves and rename the first page of the file, meaning if the current file has 5 pages. I have tried to change the numbers in the script but the issue is that each file has a different numbers of pages.

How can I rename each page of the file instead of the first page?

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript? These two are entirely different programming languages.

Comment: I am wanting to use java script

Answer (score 0):

Extract the pages to an array.

Then iterate the array of pages and do the renaming for all of them. Lets say you have an array "pageArray".

```
for(int i = 0; i < pageArray.length; i++){
   var oldFile = pageArray[i];  
   oldFile.rename ("NewName.txt");
}
```

This would iterate through all the pages and give them the same name.
If you want different names you could do:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < pageArray.length; i++)
{
    let oldFile = pageArray[i];
        oldFile.rename ("NewName" + i);
}
```

Updated answer, now it would rename all the pages "NewName" + index number.

So it would be like: NewName0, NewName1, NewName2... all the way to the end of the array.

Comment: That's the issue that I'm running into with the current script. I would have to open each file to determine the number of pages for each employee. Is there a way for the script to rename the file no matter the number of pages? I am just wanting a name convention to be added to the current file name Resume_1234 instead of 1234.

Comment: @DeeReed Updated answer

Comment: I do apologize Im a beginner when it comes to coding